# Let $X$ be a topological vector space with a countable local base. Then how does the following metric attain maximum?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space with a countable local base. Now a seminorm $p_i$ can be associated with each element of local base. From rudins book on functional analysis we get that this space is metrizable by the following metric..

$$
d(x,y)= \text{max}_{i\geq 1} \frac{c_i p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}
$$

where $c_i$ is a strictly decreasing positive sequence which decreases to $0$. How to prove that the given maximum exists? The sequence is bounded by $c_1$. for all $c_i$, $\frac{c_i p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)} < c_i$. this is beacuse $\frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}<1$. We also know that all $c_i<c_1$. Therefore the sequence is bounded by $c_1$. Now all bounded sequence need not have a maximum but always have a supremum. (For example the sequence $1-\frac{1}{i}$ with $i\geq1$ is bounded and has a supremum but does not have a defined maximum.)

But this sequence has a maximum and this has got something to do with $\frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}$ being less than $1$. Can someone give a hint here ...

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{c_i p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}\le c_i\to 0$ as $i \to \infty$ and any sequence of non-negative numbers which tends to $0$ has  a maximum.